# Should I answer bad questions or is that unethical?

Tags: discussion

If someone asks a question with an easy solution, but it's about to be closed or it has many downvotes, can I answer it or is it like I am stealing the reputation? Personally, I thought that helping someone could be always useful, but maybe I shouldn't answer and just comment that he should read the website rules and write the question again?

Comment: Mods do that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65286056/calculate-numbers-in-array-run-length-decoding, so should be fine.

Comment: Why are you answering questions that you know will be closed?  If they are being closed, why isn't the question being improved, to avoid that outcome?

Answer (score 12):

Questions with easy solutions aren't *against the rules*. Downvotes are only an expression of how useful the question is overall, which is...not very much.

This is the Catch-22 of the site; if a question is otherwise on-topic but is not that good, then no amount of prose will salvage it from downvotes because *it's not that good*.  You can contribute an answer in the hopes that someone will have a better opinion of the quality of the question, but it's not exactly an easy thing to accomplish.

Comment: some questions are useful and are downvoted anyway

Comment: In this instance I'd conjecture if the answer is damn easy to find then its usefulness is questionable at best.  Some useful questions that aren't that easy to find are also downvoted but that's not easily explained.  That could be the work of trolls or those with a vendetta.  It's not black and white @nbk since voting will always have some level of subjectivity.